# How to use getSize() method with FineUploader jQuery wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I'm using jQuery wrapper for FineUploader. I would like to get the size of the submitted file. **Without** the jQuery wrapper, one would do it like this:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
   ...
   callbacks: {
      onSubmit: function(id, name) {
         var size = this.getSize(id); // Gets the file size
         ...
      }
   },
   ...
});
```

How do I correctly do it **with** the wrapper? All the versions below fail with errors:

```
$elem.fineUploader({    
    fileSizeOnSubmit: true,    
    // other options...
}).on('submit', function(e, id, filename) {
    console.log($(this).getSize(id)); // fails
    console.log(this.getSize(id)); // fails
    console.log($elem.getSize(id)); // fails
});
```

Comment: Please just don't use the jquery wrapper. [It provides zero benefit over non-wrapped Fine Uploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1310).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I could not find any feedback on the Internet, so I ended up using the native FineUploader way:

```
$elem.fineUploader({    
    // options...
    callbacks: {
        onSubmit: function(id, filename) {
            console.log(this.getSize(id)); // Works
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I believe the way I was looking for is simply this:

```
var size = $uploader.fineUploader('getSize', parseInt(id, 10));
```

The pattern (`$elem.fineUploader(method_name, params)`) works with any other method.

Comment: Save yourself some bytes and omit the jquery wrapper here. There is no benefit to using it.

Comment: @RayNicholus: Actually I was thinking the same thing. I'm using jQuery in general in the app, but indeed, I don't see a real benefit from using the wrapper here. Question is, why is the wrapper even out there? ;)

Comment: It exists to comfort those tied to jQuery, but that's not a good enough reason for it to exist.

Comment: True. Anyway, great work with FineUploader, thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks. And now a shameless plug that was borne out of my realization that jQuery is almost always unnecessary: https://leanpub.com/beyondjquery